# How Could I pass the selected Cell on UITableViewController with UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I have **UITableViewController** which pop  **UIActionSheet** when user click on a cell with **accessoryType =UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;**

Now the method  `-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {` works fine, except, i dont know in which cell user clicked.

I could , for example, declare a property where I save selected cell in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {` but I think there must be a better way.

Comment: I would personally create a local variable with the currently selected indexPath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your table only have one section, you could store which row presented the action sheet in the tag, something like this.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sheet for row %i", indexPath.row];
    UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:title delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Option 1", @"Option 2", nil];
    [sheet setTag:indexPath.row];
    [sheet showInView:self.view];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    int row = actionSheet.tag;
    NSLog(@"Selected actionSheet buttonIndex %i for row: %i", buttonIndex, row);
}
```

It's probably the easiest way, but I wouldn't say it's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I usually set the action sheet's tag to be the index path's row, but that only works if you don't care about the section number. If you do need the section as well, creating a property would be the best way to go about it.

You could also mess with a category and associated objects, but for me personally that would be too involved.

Answer (score 2):

Implement this `UITableView` delegate method to get the index path of the cell when the accessory button is tapped:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```